# onclick event for document preventing events for an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

I have an external JS with such a code

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown",docclick,1);
document.addEventListener("click",docclick,1);
```

And my JS containing:

```
$("#close").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#box").remove();
});
```

The former code is preventing my code from execution. How to make my code running as well?

Comment: Have you tried attaching the close event before the docclick?

Comment: Yes, my JS is called before the external one,

Answer (score 1):

Because the external JS is attached to the `document` and is configured the use capture (indicated by the 1, in the method call), it is likely trapping the click event before it gets to your event listener. You need to remove their listener and reattach it without the use capture like so:

```
//Remove the offending event listener
document.removeEventListener("click",docclick,1);
//Add your listener
$('#close').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#box").remove();
});
//Reattach the offending event listener, without capture
document.addEventListener("click",docclick);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Removal of the listener works fine, but adding it back has the same effect as the original code, I uploaded the files here http://ulozto.net/x5coQ8YX/code-zip ho1.js contains the removeEventListener